# simultaneous equation help

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Can someone help me with to solve this system of equations ?

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c} 
y=x+1 \\
y^2+2x^2=2
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. You should show some effort in order to get better help. What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: First try substituting the first equation into the second equation, getting $(x+1)^2+2x^2=2$. Now you can solve that using the quadratic equation and plug it back in to get $y$.

Comment: I did try but got stuck at 3x^2+2x=1. I thought about factorizing this into x(3x+2)=1 but didn't know what to do from here.

Comment: @ethan Well you can always apply the quadratic equation (or say notice $-1$ works, and find the other root from that).

Answer (score 1):

We know from equation one that $y = x+1$. Plugging this value into equation two we get 
\begin{align*}
y^2+2x^2 &= (x+1)^2+2x^2 \\
&=x^2+2x+1+2x^2\\
&=3x^2+2x+1 \\
\end{align*}
We know that $3x^2+2x+1 = 2$ from equation two. Simplifying we get $$3x^2+2x-1 = 0$$$$(x+1)(3x-1) = 0 \tag{factoring}$$
$$x = -1, \frac{1}{3}$$Plugging in these values of $x$ into $y = x+1$ we get that $y=0, \dfrac43$ So the solutions are $$\boxed{\left(-1,0\right)\ \& \left(\frac13, \frac43\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{cases} y=x+1 \\ { y }^{ 2 }+2{ x }^{ 2 }=2 \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} y=x+1 \\ { \left( x+1 \right)  }^{ 2 }+2{ x }^{ 2 }=2 \end{cases}\Rightarrow 3{ x }^{ 2 }+2x-1=0\quad \Rightarrow x=\frac { -1\pm 2 }{ 3 } ,y=1+\frac { -1\pm 2 }{ 3 } \\ $$